# parsing csv into variables

Tags: python, parsing, variables, csv

I'm very new to python and am trying to get some code to work. I've looked at examples but can't quite get them adjusted to my needs. Here's what's going on.

I have a CSV file with each row consisting of data like name, address, email, etc. What I need to do is take the first row (or last, doesn't really matter) and parse each value into it's own variable and then delete that row.

Like I said, I've looked at examples but can't quite get it to work how I need and I'm sure there is a lot of unneeded code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at, and use, the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

If you need to change the file on disk, you should read in the data you need, and then re-write the file with the new desired content. Deleting a single row from a text file is not easy.

Comment: Well, that's just it. I have been looking at that but I can't get it. This file has lots of names and I really only need it to read the first or last line. I can't have it reading the entire file every time it runs. When I try to adapt the examples I just can't get it.

Comment: I have this so far, based on an example, but it seems like there's a lot of unnecessary code.

def readCSV(filename):
 import csv
 lines = []

 f = open(filename)
 csvReader = csv.reader( f, delimiter="," )

 for row in csvReader:
   lines.append(row)

 return lines


data = readCSV("names.csv")
GivenName = data[1][0]
StreetAddress = data[1][1]
City = data[1][2]
State = data[1][3]
Zip = data[1][4]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by 'delete'. I am assuming you want to remove it from the file? There isn't really any simple way to do that beyond reading in all the data from the file to memory, deleting the record you don't want and writing the data back. Pretty expensive operation just to remove one record from the file.

In terms of actually reading in the file and storing each value into it's own array, using the csv module allows you to read the file line by line as an array of all the comma delimited values.

```
#example of reading in a csv file and operating on each row (python 2.7)

import csv
import sys

f = open('test.csv', 'r') #open file
try:
    r = csv.reader(f) #init csv reader
    for row in r:
        #assuming we have the format -  name, address, ph num
        print row[0] #prints name
        print row[1] #prints address
        print row[2] #prints ph num
finally:
    f.close() #cleanup
```

Comment: thats helpful but how can i delete a line? it may not be necessary but it's the only thing i can think of. heres what im trying to do. i have a csv full of those names but the script is only ran once a day and i dont want it to repeat names. so i was going to have it grab the first name on the list and then delete the line so it isnt a repeat the next day.